# FPdf - echo input into table header

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm doing a monthly report and I want to echo at my table header the selected month in my drop down list here is my code:

```
$month=$_POST['month'];
$year=$_POST['year'];
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('auth');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    // Page header
    function Header1()
    {
        // Logo
        $this->Image('header.png',30,10,150);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',15);
        $this->Cell(0,89,'Employee Leave Monthly Report',0,0,'C');
        $this->Ln(53);
    }
```

how can I print the $month in my header? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding `$month` will print out the month. For example if you wanted to change "Employee Leave Monthly Report" to "Employee Leave Monthly Report for May" (where May is the month in the $month variable) you would have@

```
$this->Cell(0,89,"Employee Leave Monthly Report for $month",0,0,'C');
```

EDIT: Try this

```
$this->Cell(0,89,'Employee Leave Monthly Report for ' . $month,0,0,'C');
```

Comment: @Boots Do you have single or double quotes around that line if text?

Comment: I only have single when I make it double there's an error

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: month in C:\xampp1\htdocs\arvin3\public\pdf2\month.php on line 17
FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Comment: @Boots that would mean there is something wrong with the variable $month.

Comment: yes, but when make it only single quote it has no error doesn't print the month..

Comment: But its working and printing in the table.. how could I fixed this? :(

Answer (score 0):

The answer seem to be just `$_POST[month]`